# Programmatic table row with text and a button

Tags: java, android

I have this layout which presents my View correctly, I tried to match it with Java side to have the capability to build rows dynamically, but I kept failing into achieving that,

```
 <TableLayout> 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextViewaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaws" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
            </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I do want to make it in code, I have tried many times and this is my best attempt

```
public static void makeTablePostOrders(Context ct, TableLayout tableLayout_PostOrders,
                                   List<String> postOrders)
{
    TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);



//randoms
for(int i = 0; i < postOrders.size()/2 ; i++)
{
    //make tableRow
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(ct);
    // make LinearLayout
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ct);
    layout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //make TextView
    TextView tv = new TextView(ct);
    tv.setText(postOrders.get(i));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    // make button
    // the button should send us to next view
    Button bt_View = new Button(ct);
    bt_View.setText("Select");

    //adding views
    layout.addView(tv,-2,-2);
    tableRow.addView(layout);
    tableRow.addView(bt_View,-2,-2);
    tableLayout_PostOrders.addView(tableRow,i+1);
}
}
```

What I want is to make table ROWs with Text and a Button, yet the text should not pass the screen and always go down vertically if needed.

here is a picture, each row will have one of these.

[image]

Comment: any reason for  `android:layout_width="200dp"` of linear layout

Comment: that is an attempt to not make it pass the screen, i am new into this

Comment: Please share the snapshot of expected output and the output you are getting from this code.

Comment: added picture as asked @SweetWisherツ

Comment: Great.. I will post the solution soon.

Comment: I think you're good with this https://ibb.co/hmH7Jw

Comment: yes looks good as needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156676/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-honeydipper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to implement the design according to yr requirement is listview or recyclerview.
So best to use **Listview/RecycleView** instead of making list row on fly.

The xml for the list row will look like :

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".65"
            android:text="You text will come here" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to look into these and the XML is perfect